# Is RefCell ever useful on its own

Tags: rust, refcell

It might seem like a strange question, but "interior mutability" cells in Rust are always explained *and* used in a context where they're used together with some kind of shared pointer. And indeed it seems pretty useless on its own, since you get interior mutability with no way to share it.

So here is my question: Is it ever useful ? And if it is not (and never used), what's the point of not providing a RefCell that is *also* a shared pointer ?

Comment: Do you mean "why doesn't the standard library have a type like `RcRefCell` that is equivalent to `Rc<RefCell>`?", or do you mean "what's the point of having `RefCell` as a type if only `Rc<RefCell>` is useful?"

Comment: `RefCell` is useful on its own to provide an easy and safe path to interior mutability when the use case is incompatible with the current capabilities of the compiler to prove that a given architecture is memory safe.

Comment: If you consider `&` a shared pointer, then sure, interior mutability is useless without shared pointer. If you consider only `Rc` and friends to be shared pointers, then interior mutability is very useful even without them. In fact, just yesterday I had a use case for interior mutability with shared references (albeit I used `Cell` and not `RefCell`, and although this was not strictly necessary but I used this to simplify the code and minimize unsafe code).

Comment: Also notice that `Rc<RefCell>` is somewhat an antipattern (but each alone is not, and `Arc<Mutex>` is not).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `Rc<RefCell>` is used as an example in the official docs, which say this is "common" - if it is considered an antipattern, what's the reason (and where can I read more)?

Comment: @kaya3 I said "somewhat", because sometimes it is fine. Sometimes it is used to bypass ownership (sometimes even because lack of understanding), and this is usually bad. But sometimes it is used just as shared mutability, and this is fine.

Comment: It's an antipattern in the sense that it is often possible to replace it entirely with something that doesn't need `Rc` or `RefCell`, and that this other approach is nearly always preferable. However, if you do need to write code with a graph of pointers in some complicated web, and the alternatives don't apply for some reason, then `Rc<RefCell>` is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RefCell` is not always directly inside the `Rc`. For example, this kind of struct can be quite useful:

```rs
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct SharedVec<T> {
    inner: RefCell<Vec<T>>,
}

impl<T> SharedVec<T> {
    fn push(&self, value: T) {
        self.inner.borrow_mut().push(value);
    }
    fn pop(&self) -> Option<T> {
        self.inner.borrow_mut().pop()
    }
}
```

And then, you might have an `Rc<SharedVec<T>>`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the explanation I was looking for

Comment: I am not sure I understand the benefit of having inner as a RefCell...instead of just breing a Vec<T>

Comment: The benefit is that the `push` and `pop` methods can take `&self` even though they modify the vector. You might argue that you should just put an `RefCell` around the `SharedVec` in the place you are storing it instead, but then you have to call `borrow_mut()` every time you interact with it, which is cumbersome. It's nicer to hide the `borrow_mut()` calls inside `push`/`pop` so that the user of `SharedVec` does not have to see them.